# creating OP_RETURN script on bitcoin core console. i.e. with the help of commands

Tags: bitcoind, raw-transaction, op-return

I want to create a OP_RETURN script on bitcoin core console. Not using GUI, i.e. available on proofofexistence.com , Just as we create raw transaction and then sign it and then broadcast it, I am curious about how to create OP_RETURN script. Anyone here can give reference or want to share their knowledge? Step by step explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`createrawtransaction` has an option for `data`. That will create an OP_RETURN output with whatever hex-encoded data you want in it. So you would have a `createrawtransaction` command that looks something like this:

```
createrawtransaction '[]' '{"data":"deadbeef"}'
```